# Could not resolve proxy

Tags: proxy

I am trying to connect to the internet through Ubuntu while I am on my company VPC using commands like curl, ping, git push, etc. When doing this, I get the below message:

Could not resolve proxy: {proxy_address}

I use the exact same proxy settings for git bash, and everything works. If I disconnect from my VPC everything works with Ubuntu. Is there something specific to Ubuntu that I have to do for the proxy to resolve?